# How can I make a pixel-perfect web site with Bootstrap 3's non-integer column widths?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm perplexed by Bootstrap 3's non-integer column widths.

According to the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), the container width for "small devices" is 750px.  That includes 11 gutters of 30px each (330px total) leaving 420px, divided by 12 columns gives 35px per column.  Okay.

But the container width for "medium devices" is 970px.  Again subtracting 330px gives 640px, which divided by 12 is 53.33px.  Huh?  How does this work?  Does it mean that I get two columns of 53px followed by one of 54px, or what?

Does anyone understand why Twitter didn't just make the column width 54px for "medium devices" and make the container width 978px?

Comment: Try reading this... it may help you a bit more... http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-grid-system.php - The max column width for "medium devices" is actually 81px, because the size is set in between a set of values.

Comment: "Does anyone understand why Twitter": Bootstrap actually isn't affiliated with Twitter anymore.

Comment: Re: "Why?": Basically, people are human and make mistakes: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12808#issuecomment-47717422

Comment: Interesting thread.  I think the math is off.  You can't just divide the container width by 12 to get the column width because while there are 12 columns, there are only 11 gutters.  You have to subtract out the gutter space and then divide the remaining width by 12. The column widths are (750-330)/12=35 for sm, (970-330)/12=53.33 for md, and (1170-330)/12=70 for lg.

Comment: Friendlier sizes would be 36 for sm, 54 for md, and 72 for lg.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a fixed width grid, then Twitter Bootstrap probably isn't the right framework for you.

The Bootstrap grid is percentage based and is designed as a mobile-first, responsive grid.  In short, it allows you to specify how your grid should behave between specific breakpoints.

The sm breakpoint is at 768px, thus if you want to target devices that are 768px or more you use the col-sm-* classes.  The * is a value that represents a grid unit of 1-12.  Therefore, col-sm-6 will be 50% (i.e. 6/12) of the containing row width on all devices that are 768px or more.  It will **not** be 384px.  Assuming that the row is the full width of the screen, it will be 50% of whatever the screen width is (less padding for gutters).

Comment: I understand how the Bootstrap grid works.  I'm not looking or a fixed-width grid.  However, I'd like the width of the grid columns to be an integer number of pixels, like 50, or 60, not 53.33.  If I was using the fluid grid, then the widths could be anything, but with the regular grid, given width >= 768, the column widths are fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to ditch responsiveness, you can use the `xs` column classes. These retain a fixed width which is determined based on your container width. See: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options